# User entry - path autocompletion

Tags: ruby, bash, autocomplete

In my ruby script, I need to read a user entry which is a path.

So, I want to read a user entry with the same type of auto-completion as in a terminal (using TAB).

Because I didn't find a simple way to do that, I think about using a bash command :

```
path = `read -e -p "Enter your path: "`
```

But I get an error :

```
``': No such file or directory - read -e (Errno::ENOENT)
```

If someone have any explanation for this error or a ruby solution to do that, that would be great :)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT :

It seems I'm not very clear : I want (in the middle of a ruby script) to get a user entry, for example like this :

```
path = STDIN.gets.chomp
```

But with gets, there isn't auto-completion for path. So I was wondering if there is a simple way to use gets (or any other method) WITH auto-completion.

Because I don't know any solution, I tried to use the bash command `read` with the -e option.
This works well in a terminal but when I put it in my ruby script surrounded by quotes, I get the error above.

In fact :

```
#! /bin/bash
read -e -p "Enter your path: "
echo $REPLY
```

works well, whereas

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
`read -e -p "Enter your path: "`
`echo $REPLY`
```

doesn't works --> Why ?

Comment: Could you please provide some more code? For example the part where you are actually calling the bash command.

Comment: I make a new ruby file with just the line I put here and get the same error so it's this line which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not gonna work with bash command. Try using [thor](http://whatisthor.com/)
eg:

```
require "thor"

class MyCLI < Thor
  desc "path /path/to/file", "select path"
  def path(p)
    puts "selected path #{p}"
  end
end

MyCLI.start(ARGV)
```

and then in consol autocomplete for path should work

```
$ ruby ./t.rb path /home…
```

Comment: I don't want to pass this entry through the arguments, I want to ask for it in the middle of my code.
But it's a good tool, I will surely use it another time so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`echo "Enter your path: ";read path`

Comment: Without -e option, the command read doesn't do auto-completion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `readline` library. For example:

```
require 'readline'

Readline.completion_proc = Proc.new do |str|
  Dir[str + '*'].grep( /^#{Regexp.escape(str)}/ )
end

file = File.open(Readline.readline('File Name> ').strip!)
```

More information: http://bogojoker.com/readline/